# Find average in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table I am having say 5 numbers. I want to find moving average of 3 numbers.

Query I am using is

```
select avg(value) over(order by value rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding) as average 
from test;
```

I want my query to start finding average from 4th value as first three values will not be having 3 previous values to calculate from. Please suggest.

Comment: You want the average of every cell's number in a row, starting from a row that is lower than the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The average will work for the first three -- it will just either be `NULL` or based on fewer than 3 rows.

But, you can do what you want using `row_number()`;

```
select (case when row_number() over (order by value) > 3
             then avg(value) over (order by value rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding)
        end) as average 
from test;
```